# Restore Position in UIWebView

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, uiwebview, state-restoration

I need to store the current position in a UIWebView to disk and reload it from disk on a later launch.

What I did before was to store the `window.scrollX` and `window.scrollY` with an javascript position.
This works good for many cases.

Additionally I store the scale by getting the current:

```
webView.scrollView.zoomScale
```

and restore it by setting the viewports initial scale to it with javascript.

All of this works but isn't reliable. Is there an better way?

I read about `UIWebView`'s `restorationIdentifier` but I'm not sure if I can save it to disk?

Comment: what are you storing the value with java script for(reason)? I don't understand. Could you please clarify the question and maybe include some code so we can see what exactly you're doing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In iOS 6 and later, if you assign a value to this view’s
>   restorationIdentifier property, it attempts to preserve its URL
>   history, the scaling and scrolling positions for each page, and
>   information about which page is currently being viewed. During
>   restoration, the view restores these values so that the web content
>   appears just as it did before.

See more from [Apple Programming Guide](http://nathanmock.com/files/com.apple.adc.documentation.AppleiOS6.0.iOSLibrary.docset/Contents/Resources/Documents/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/StatePreservation/StatePreservation.html) and a [tutorial](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2013/05/23/restoration-classes-and-uiwebviews.html) along with a sample project. You can run it and send the app to the background, then stop running it with Xcode, next time you open the app, it will restore its state to the state before app entering to the background. There can be a small fix on the sample project, in `viewDidAppear`, if `self.restoringState` is `NO`, you call `showPage` function.

Comment: For some reason I can't use state preservation exactly as described because I can't assure that the view is the first to appear after the app being open.

Is there a way to preserve the state to disk? I also need to make sure that the web view has refreshed content and keeps the same position (I know that it can't be always the exact position because of site changes but this is ok)

Comment: You can use `NSUserDefault` to save `contentOffSet` and `zoomScale` as a `NSDictionary`, next time you open the app, you reload the request to refresh the content, in `webViewDidFinishLoad`, you reset your webView's `contentOffset` and webView's scrollView zoomScale.

Comment: This is what I do currently. But sometimes it makes wrong positions and setting the zoom scale isn't reliable

Comment: What is not reliable? The zoom scale is not working? I just did a test and it is working for me.

Answer (score 1):

Just to be clear, the steps for UIWebView state restoration (similar to the normal state restoration) are as follows:

1. In your app delegate `application: shouldRestoreApplicationState`, `application: shouldSaveApplicationState` return true.
2. Presented view controller- set its Restoration ID - you can do it in the storyboard's identity inspector. The ID can be any unique string. If you have a container VC (navigation, etc) you need to set a restoration ID for it.
3. Set the Restoration ID for the UIWebView in your storyboard
4. Override `applicationFinishedRestoringState` and reload the `webView`

I used these step, and everything seemed to work. However, after reading your comments I saw you were having problems with zoomed pages. The problem is a bug in UIWebView restoration (I think) and it has to do with the reloading mechanism. That's why I suggest the following hack:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var webView: UIWebView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        webView.delegate = self
        webView.scrollView.restorationIdentifier = "webViewScrollView"
    }

    var restoring = false
    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        if !restoring {
            webView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://google.com")!))
        }

    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    var restoredScrollOffset: CGPoint = CGPoint.zeroPoint
    override func applicationFinishedRestoringState() {
        restoring = true
        restoredScrollOffset = webView.scrollView.contentOffset
        webView.reload()
    }

    func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView) {
        if restoring {
            restoring = false
            if webView.scrollView.contentOffset != restoredScrollOffset {
                println("bug - sometimes it may happen")
            }
            webView.scrollView.contentOffset = restoredScrollOffset
        }
   }
```

because it's a hack we can't be sure it will be flawless :)

Note that I set the restoration identifier of the scroll view within the webview, just so I wouldn't have to implement the VC encode function - it's possible to encode only the scrollview offset via the VC encode/decode overrides.

I only set the scroll view offset; if you have problems with the zoom scale (which I didn't find in any web page I tried) you can just set the scale in the same place I set the content offset of the scroll view

The code is in https://github.com/iamdoron/UIWebViewRestoration